# Dropdown Asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, angularjs, json

Gostaria de fazer dois dropdown numa view, não quero fazer esses dropdown através do model na view porque cada dropdown é de uma classe diferente.

Fiz os dropdowns com o angular.js só que eu não consegui obter os valores ao submeter o formulário.

Gostaria de fazer esses dropdowns com chamada Get via Json ou Ajax.

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta colocando nela o código já desenvolvido?

Comment: Você quer com Angular? Talvez [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76296/20615) possa lhe ajudar. Basta realizar a requisição `Ajax` ao carregar a página.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos consegui popular o `DropDownList` via `ajax` da seguinte forma:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetAntera()
    {
        var List = db.Antera.ToList();
        return this.Json(List, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Script

```
function Teste() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Angiosperma/GetAntera/",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#teste").empty();
            $("#teste").append('<option value>Selecione...</option>');
            $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                $("#teste").append('<option value="' + element.Id + '">' + element.NOME + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    Teste();
});
```

View:

```
<select id="teste" name="teste" ></select>
```