# SQL - Restringir dados da query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Bom dia,

Tenho uma app em `WebForms` que a partir de duas `DropDownList` obtem dados de uma base de dados em `MS SQL Server 2012`.

Na primeira `DropDownList` ele vai apresentar o nome de várias empresas na base de dados com o seguinte `SELECT statement`:´

```
SELECT [nome] FROM [empresas]
```

Na segunda `DropDownList` ele irá apresentar uma lista de empregados que estão associados a essa empresa selecionada acima, visto que na tabela de empregados está associado o código da empresa ao empregado. Mas no entanto não percebi como posso resolver isso, atualmente ele apresenta todos os empregados na base de dados sem restringir nada, estando com o `SELECT statement` básico de:

```
SELECT [nome] FROM [colaboradores]
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Usando uma clausula `where`?

Comment: As duas DropDownList estão na mesma página e você quer que os dados da primeira modifiquem os resultados da segunda sem que a página seja recarregada, é isso?

Comment: @FleuquerLima exatamente

Comment: Poderia utilizar ajax para isso. Veja essa resposta do colega Cigano Morrison: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76255/como-popular-um-dropdownlist-a-partir-de-outro-dropdownlist e essa http://www.daviferreira.com/posts/populando-selects-de-cidades-e-estados-com-ajax-php-e-jquery ou essa http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/15560-como-carregar-dropdown-dianico-no-update/

Answer (score 1):

Você pode carregar o DropDownList da sua tabela Empresas no `Page_Load`, e preencher a propriedade `IsPostBack` com o valor True.

Para carregar o DropDownList de colaboradores, voce pode usar o evento `SelectedIndexChanged` do DropDownList Empresa e efetuar a consulta informando qual foi a empresa selecionada.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```HTML
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EmpresaColaboradores.aspx.cs" Inherits="stackoverflow.EmpresaColaboradores" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="Label">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblIdEmpresa" runat="server" Text="Empresas"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="Field">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIdEmpresa" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlIdEmpresa_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Label">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblIdColaboradore" runat="server" Text="Colaboradores"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="Field">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIdColaboradore" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Content>
```

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    namespace stackoverflow
    {
        public partial class EmpresaColaboradores : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (IsPostBack)
                    return;

                using (var ctx = new stackoverflowEntities())
                {
                    var qrCategoria = ctx.Categoria.ToList();

                    ddlIdEmpresa.DataTextField = "Nome";
                    ddlIdEmpresa.DataValueField = "CategoriaId";
                    ddlIdEmpresa.DataSource = qrCategoria;
                    ddlIdEmpresa.DataBind();

                }
                ddlIdEmpresa_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
            }

            protected void ddlIdEmpresa_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var IdEmpresa = Convert.ToInt32(ddlIdEmpresa.SelectedValue);
                ddlIdColaboradore.Items.Clear();
                ddlIdColaboradore.Enabled = IdEmpresa > 0;

                if (IdEmpresa > 0)
                {
                    using (var ctx = new stackoverflowEntities())
                    {
                        var qrSubCategoria = ctx.SubCategoria
                            .Where(sc => sc.CategoriaId == IdEmpresa)
                            .ToList();

                        ddlIdColaboradore.DataTextField = "Nome";
                        ddlIdColaboradore.DataValueField = "SubCategoriaId";
                        ddlIdColaboradore.DataSource = qrSubCategoria;
                        ddlIdColaboradore.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Veja os resultados:

[image: Resultado da combo empresas]
[image: Resultado da combo colaboradores, com a empresa selecionada]

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar a instrução a seguir para recuperar os nomes dos colaboradores:

> SELECT [nome] FROM [colaboradores] WHERE [IdEmpresa] = @Variável_IdEmpresa

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o sistema de parâmetros de pesquisa do SQL.

Quando você usa:

```sql
    SELECT [nome] FROM [colaboradores];
```

Ele Pega todos os colaboradores, já que você não define um parâmetro de procura.

```sql
    SELECT [nome] FROM [colaboradores] WHERE id_empresa = `ID DA EMPRESA`;
```

Ele só pega os colaboradores que no "id_empresa", seja igual ao id que veio da outra lista.